# Изменить размер шрифта выводимого текста

Tags: html

Есть скрипт(ниже), который выводит дату с определенными условиями. Нужно размер шрифта выходного текста сделать 34.

````
<script>
    var date = new Date();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var day = date.getDate();
    if (month == 0,3,5,7,9,11 && day >= 31) {month += 1;day = 0;} // Проверка для переходя на след. месяц 
    else {if (month == 2 && day >= 28) {month += 1;day = 0;} 
    else {if (day >= 30) {month +=1;day = 0;}}}
    if (hour < 18) {
     if(day == 0) {day = 1);}
        switch (month) {
            case 0:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " января";
                break;
            case 1:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " февраля";
                break;
            case 2:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " марта";
                break;
            case 3:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " апреля";
                break;
            case 4:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " мая";
                break;
            case 5:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " июня";
                break;
            case 6:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " июля";
                break;
            case 7:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " августа";
                break;
            case 8:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " сентября";
                break;
            case 9:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " октября";
                break;
            case 10:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " ноября";
                break;
            case 11:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " декабря";
                break;
        }
    } else {

        switch (month) {
            case 0:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " января";
                break;
            case 1:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " февраля";
                break;
            case 2:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " марта";
                break;
            case 3:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " апреля";
                break;
            case 4:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " мая";
                break;
            case 5:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " июня";
                break;
            case 6:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " июля";
                break;
            case 7:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " августа";
                break;
            case 8:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " сентября";
                break;
            case 9:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " октября";
                break;
            case 10:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " ноября";
                break;
            case 11:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " декабря";
                break;
        }
    }
</script>```
````

Answer (score 1):

```js
var date = new Date();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var day = date.getDate();
    if (month == 0,3,5,7,9,11 && day >= 31) {month += 1;day = 0;} // Проверка для переходя на след. месяц 
    else {if (month == 2 && day >= 28) {month += 1;day = 0;} 
    else {if (day >= 30) {month +=1;day = 0;}}}
    if (hour < 16) {
     if(day == 0) {day = 1;}
        switch (month) {
            case 0:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " января";
                break;
            case 1:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " февраля";
                break;
            case 2:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " марта";
                break;
            case 3:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " апреля";
                break;
            case 4:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " мая";
                break;
            case 5:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " июня";
                break;
            case 6:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " июля";
                break;
            case 7:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " августа";
                break;
            case 8:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " сентября";
                break;
            case 9:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " октября";
                break;
            case 10:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " ноября";
                break;
            case 11:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " декабря";
                break;
        }
    } else {

        switch (month) {
            case 0:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " января";
                break;
            case 1:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " февраля";
                break;
            case 2:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " марта";
                break;
            case 3:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " апреля";
                break;
            case 4:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " мая";
                break;
            case 5:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " июня";
                break;
            case 6:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " июля";
                break;
            case 7:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " августа";
                break;
            case 8:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " сентября";
                break;
            case 9:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " октября";
                break;
            case 10:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " ноября";
                break;
            case 11:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " декабря";
                break;
        }
    }
```

```css
#hours {
  font-size: 34px;
}
```

```html
<div id="hours"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а куда этот фрагмент вставлять?

Comment: @АлинаВоропаева ну, код `#hours {
  font-size: 34px;
}` надо внести в тег `<style> ........... </style>`  либо в отдельный css файл, который подключить на страницу

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с решением вашей задачи

```js
const date = moment();

if (date.hours() >= 12) date.add(1, 'days');

document.getElementById("hours").innerText = date.format('DD MMMM');
```

```css
#hours {
    font-size: 34px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/locale/ru.min.js"></script>

<div id="hours"></div>
```

Comment: В том то и дело, что необходим такой скрипт, чтобы дата менялась следующим образом: до 18:00 показывалась дата сегодняшнего дня, после 18:00 показывалась уже завтрашняя дата, код не HTTP, а HTTPS и шрифт 34. Например, 4 февраля. Что-то не работает :( Можете помочь?

Comment: @АлинаВоропаева обновил ответ с вашими требованиями.